# AsyncTask onPostExecute is never called

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I tried to add override annotation and didn't work with it.

```
public class Details extends Activity {
String name = "";
String balance = "";

public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    protected void onPreExecute() {

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Details.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

NetWork netWork = new NetWork();
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("details", 0);
String user = settings.getString("user", "");
String pass = settings.getString("pass", "");

String s="";
try {
    s = netWork.getGradesHtml(
            "https://app.laundro-smart.com/Forms/frmMain.aspx", user, pass,
            "GET",0,3,0,"");
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}


int index = Jsoup
        .parse(s,
                "https://app.laundro-smart.com/Forms/frmMacineStateInRegion.aspx")
        .select("span#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblPrePaidBalance")
        .toString().lastIndexOf("<");

 balance =Jsoup.parse(s,
                        "https://app.laundro-smart.com/Forms/frmMacineStateInRegion.aspx")
                        .select("span#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblPrePaidBalance")
                        .toString().substring(55, index);
index = Jsoup
        .parse(s,
                "https://app.laundro-smart.com/Forms/frmMacineStateInRegion.aspx")
        .select("span#ctl00_lnkUsername").toString()
        .lastIndexOf("<");
name= Jsoup.parse(s,
                        "https://app.laundro-smart.com/Forms/frmMacineStateInRegion.aspx")
                        .select("span#ctl00_lnkUsername")
                        .toString().substring(58, index);
                        return name;    
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String aa) {

        TextView a = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        a.setText(aa);
        a =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        a.setText(balance);
        progressDialog.cancel();

    }

}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);
    (new MyTask()).execute();           


}
```

Comment: it should or your app may be crashing and you need to give more details do you see progress bar?

Comment: yes i see a progress bar, and the app didn't crash,the progress dialog is loading forever.

Comment: then check the doInbackground part. Your asynctask executes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an example code you edit and try this code. This code is to download file from the internet and once the download is completed it will take to the other activity 

public class asyncDownloader extends AsyncTask<string, String, String> {

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String path=Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/SimonSong.mp3";
        Log.e("simon", "Path is "+path);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Constants.BROAD);
        intent.putExtra("test", path);
        sendBroadcast(intent);

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Toast.makeText(this, "async class is called",
        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e("simon", "async class is called");
        int count;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();

            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();
            Log.e("simon", "download is started");
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),
                    10 * 1024);

            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/SimonSong.mp3");
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0;
            Prog pg = new Prog();
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;

                int temp = (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile);                
                //Log.e("simon", "Downloading completed " + temp + " %");
                output.write(data, 0, count);
                pg.setUpdate(temp);
            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();




            //Log.e("simon", "download is finished");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        //Log.e("simon","Value  :  "+values[0]);
    }


}
```